# model reveal issue with ajax call in foundation-zurb

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, zurb-foundation

i am trying to make ajax call with model reveal in my application.

able to pass dynamic id in url but it reveals only last model (without ajax-call) on each click

i tried previous solution with ajax-all [Reveal Modal is revealing last value in loop iteration Foundation-zurb issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63338489/reveal-modal-is-revealing-last-value-in-loop-iteration-foundation-zurb-issue/63344309?noredirect=1#comment112034568_63344309)

but i am not able to pass dynamic id in javasript file.

model reveal reference link:- https://codepen.io/sujayjaju/pen/akAYzP?editors=1010

current code reveals one model on each reveal click i tried last solution as well(url mentioned) but it doesn't worked with ajax-call.

application.js

```
  $(document).on('open.zf.reveal', "#exampleModal1", function (e) {
var $modal = $(this);
var ajax_url = $modal.data("ajax-url");
if (ajax_url) {
  $modal.html("Now Loading: "+ajax_url);
  $.ajax(ajax_url).done(function (response) {
    $modal.html(response);
  });
}
});
```

index.html.erb

```
<% @project.project_sites.where(submission_status: true).order("created_at desc").each do |project_site| %>
  <tr>
      <td><%= project_site.user.name %></td>

       <td>
        <div class="full reveal" id="exampleModal1" data-reveal data-ajax-url="http://0.0.0.0:3000/project_sites/<%= project_site.id %>/attendances/">

         <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
         </button>
         </div>

         <p><button class="button small warning button-margin-top fi-eye" data-open="exampleModal1"> View</button></p>

       </td>
    </tr>
<%end %>
```

Comment: Please check the answer below and let me know if it does not solve the issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just found easy solution to this problem that worked:- (with internal jquery)

index.html.erb

```
<% @project.project_sites.where(submission_status: true).order("created_at desc").each do |project_site| %>
  <tr>
       <td>
           <% site_modal_id = "site_modal_#{project_site.id}" %>

                  <div class="full reveal" id="<%= site_model_id %>" data-reveal data-ajax-url="http://0.0.0.0:3000/project_sites/<%= project_site.id %>/attendances/">

              <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
           </div>

            <p><button class="button small warning button-margin-top fi-eye" data-open="<%= site_modal_id %>"> View</button></p>

       </td>
    </tr>

<script>
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });

  $(document).on('open.zf.reveal', "#<%= site_modal_id %>", function (e) {
    var $modal = $(this);
    var ajax_url = $modal.data("ajax-url");
    if (ajax_url) {
    $modal.html("Now Loading: "+ajax_url);
    $.ajax(ajax_url).done(function (response) {
      $modal.html(response);
    });
    }
  });

});
</script>
<%end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this [particular commit](https://github.com/AquisTech/expense_tracker/commit/d807937e0cdfebcf802230f74d3080ac0e1fe841) from my application which is well.

Javascript Code

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $(document).foundation();
  $('[data-open="ajax-reveal"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: $(this).data('url'),
      success: function(result) {
        $(".reveal-content").html(result);
      },
      error: function(result) {
        $(".reveal-content").html('Error loading content. Please close popup and retry.');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

HAML Code

```
          #ajax-reveal.reveal{'data-reveal': true, 'aria-labelledby':"modalTitle", 'aria-hidden': true, role: "dialog"}
            .reveal-content
            %button.close-button{'aria-label': "Close modal", type: :button, data: {close: true}}
              %span{'aria-hidden': true} &times;
```

My Links look like this

```
<% @project.project_sites.where(submission_status: true).order("created_at desc").each do |project_site| %>
  <%- 'YOUR OTHER CODE' %>
  <%= link_to 'View', 'javascript:void(0)', class: 'button OTHER-CLASSES', data: {open: 'ajax-reveal', url: project_site_path(project_site)} %>
<% end %>
```

Some handy helpers that I use for reveal are

```
  def close_reveal_button(text = 'Cancel')
    content_tag(:div, text, class: 'button warning', data: {close: ''})
  end
  def link_to_reveal(content, url, classes)
    link_to content, 'javascript:void(0)', class: classes, data: {open: 'ajax-reveal', url: url}
  end
```

You can refer more helpers [here](https://github.com/AquisTech/expense_tracker/blob/master/app/helpers/application_helper.rb#L23)

Comment: Have you used all the snippets? Because it is a working code. It is used on my site which is live. Using only parts of snippet will not work. Anyway, happy that you got solution